# How to access a method by another method?

Tags: java, android

I was watching thenewboston Android tutorials and I got lost in this line of code:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

I think `getWindow()` and `setFlags()` are a method, but why they can be accessed like that? The one that I always see is `ClassObject.Method` but this time it's `Method.Method`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[getWindow()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getWindow%28%29) returns an object of type [Window](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html), on which one can use the [setFlags()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setFlags%28int,%20int%29) method

So it is basically a geeky way of writing

```
Window a = getWindow();
a.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: great answer! Personally I prefer what you wrote, I like clean code.

Comment: thank you :) yup, it is easier for other developers to follow this code as well.

Answer (score 2):

Because `getWindows()` is a Method from the Class `Activity`.
And it returns an object from the Class `Window` which represents your actuall Screen-window.
So `setFlags()` is actually called on the Window-Class.

Answer (score 1):

It works because the first method(from the activity) returns an object (`Window`) on which you can call the second method. You could do :

```
Window obj = getWindow();
obj.setFlags();
```

if it makes more sense to you.