# Initialize an object

Tags: java, android, oop

Contiuned from : [This is my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9565488/how-to-access-a-method-by-another-method)

So now i can use this code :

```
Window a = getWindow();
    a.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Instead of this code :

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

And some of my Senior's said that because of `getWindow();` method is returning a Window Object we can use both of the code above. 
My question is : why we need to get a returned Window object from this code : `Window a = getWindow();`

I think when i do this i already have a Window Object

```
Window a;
```

But why is it not working?

And my 2nd question is why can't i do like this :

```
Window a = new Window();
```

I think it's create a Window object too.

Why must I use the `getWindow();` method?

Thanks all

PS: English is not my native language, so sorry if I made some mistakes

Comment: [Type]Window [name]a [assignment]= [inovakation]getWindow(), getWindow() returns an Window by declaring a type you are letting the compiler know what the variable will be

Comment: If you write like Window a; it will return a window instance. Window a = getWindow(); will return you the current window of that current activity. As you are changing the properties of the current window, so you have to get the current window of existing activity first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming java here:

```
Window a;
```

does not create a new `Window` object, it only creates a variable, which can hold an object of type `Window`. To create the object itself - you need to invoke its constructor, in your case - I assume that what `getWindow()` does.

Also, `new Window` is a syntax error - constructors in java are invoked similar to methods [with `()` and relevant arguments, if there are any].

Comment: Thanks Sir, yes i mean new Window(); :D
But how come getWindow(); become a constructor from Window Class?I think all constructors in Java must have the same name like it's Class..
So the constructor of Window Class is Window(param);

Sorry, i'm a beginner :D

Thanks Sir

Comment: @BlazeTama getWindow() is a method not a constructor. Probably the method itself creates an instance of Window [using new Window(...)] and return it.

Answer (score 2):

You can create an object using it's constructor. Constructor is a method.
`Window a = new Window;` is syntaxical mistake in Java. And you cant use `a` after `Window a;` because in java you have to initialize a variable before using it.
Can you write with a pen just imagining about it? you have to buy that pen at first, don't you?
`Window a = new Window();`
this will work normally if you write it instead of `Window a = new Window;`

Comment: yes Sir, sorry i miss typed that new Window(): :D
Thanks Sir :D

Answer (score 1):

Think of it like this. You're doing **Object** oriented programming, right? You can have multiple instances of an object but they're not all the same thing.

When you use getWindow(), you're getting a specific window. When you just do

```
Window a; //This will return null since the reference for some window object is created but currently points to null
```

or

```
Window a = new Window(ctx); //A window object reference is created which points to some new Window object in memory.
```

You're referencing **a** window but not **the** window you're intending on using.

I hope this clears things up. Please as if you have further questions.

Comment: Yes! Thank you. I've updated the code to reflect the current api.

Comment: Thanks Sir..but what is the constructor of Window?is it getWindow(); method?I think all constructors must have the same name  with it's Class?

It made me confuse :D

Thanks Sir :D

Comment: Not exactly. Constructors are a crucial part of Java so having a good understanding of them is crucial. 
The getWindow() method returns the current window for the activity. This means that there is already a window in existence for this activity and getWindow() just fetches it.

A constructor is very different to this. In a very general sense, the constructor is the thing that initialises an object and sets it's default values. You should really read more about the subject here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/constructors.html
And perhaps watch youtube videos.